In Java, how can a name become a member of a Primary expression?
First, let's take a look at a very simple piece of code.
class S { int x = 0; } 
class Test1 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        S s = new S(); 
        System.out.println("s.x=" + s.x);
    } 
}

s.x is a field access expression.
The following is the relevant syntax excerpted by me from the Java Language Specification:
15.11:

FieldAccess:
Primary . Identifier
super . Identifier
TypeName . super. Identifier


15.8: Primary:
PrimaryNoNewArray
ArrayCreationExpression


PrimaryNoNewArray:
Literal
ClassLiteral
this TypeName . this
( Expression )
ClassInstanceCreationExpression
FieldAccess
ArrayAccess
MethodInvocation
MethodReference

If only looking at the syntax excerpted above, then s.x seemingly does not conform to the syntax.The reason is that s seemingly does not belong to any member of the Primary expressions.
Fortunately, the specification gives an explanation later, and this is exactly where my doubt lies：

This part of the grammar of the Java programming language is unusual,
in two ways. First, one might expect simple names, such as names of
local variables and method parameters, to be primary expressions. For
technical reasons, names are grouped together with primary expressions
a little later when postfix expressions are introduced (§15.14).

"names are grouped together with primary expressions a little later when postfix expressions are introduced",My understanding of this sentence is that a name will become a member of the primary expressions under certain circumstances.
15.14:

Postfix expressions include uses of the postfix ++ and -- operators.
Names are not considered to be primary expressions (§15.8), but are
handled separately in the grammar to avoid certain ambiguities. They
become interchangeable only here, at the level of precedence of
postfix expressions.

My question is:
1.Is my above understanding correct?
2."They become interchangeable only here, at the level of precedence of
postfix expressions",
(1).What does this sentence mean?
(2).Can you explain, based on my example, why s in s.x becomes a member of the primary expressions here?(On the premise that my understanding is correct.)
(3).What is the relationship between this and the level of precedence of postfix expressions?
(4).What does "interchangeable" refer to?
Thank you for your reading.

You are asking way too many questions in one post.

I would interpret this as follows: 1) Names are not counted as primary expressions in general as they would normally be treated differently, e.g. there are cases where only expressions are expected or not allowed. 2) For postfix expressions names and primary expressions are thrown in together, i.e. they both are acceptable here. That postfix expression definition is then used in the postfix increment/decrement expression definition. 3) As for precedence - this might refer to the precedence rules how postfix operators are applied which are the same for names and primary expressions.

@Sweeper:Generally speaking, why does s.x as a field access expression conform to the syntax?(I have read user2357112's answer.)

@Thomas:Can you explain which syntax rule s.x conforms to?

It should be FieldAccess where the example uses s.x for static binding in section "15.11.1. Field Access Using a Primary".

Btw, what is the reason for this question? Is it just curiosity or is there any practical problem you're trying to solve?

@Thomas
Just out of curiosity. If s.x is a field access expression, then s should be a primary expression. However, s does not meet the syntactic requirements of a primary expression. So perhaps it is not a field access?But this example appears in FieldAccess . You can take a look at the following answer. I am also very puzzled.

Well, the spec doesn't necessarily always contain those descriptions in formal notation. Some pieces may be hidden in seemingly innocent sentences. And after all it is written by humans so may also contain some ambiguities (e.g. accessing a field via a named reference is so basic that it might just be added to the descriptions in everyone's heads).

s.x is not a primary expression, and does not "become a member of the primary expressions" at any point. s.x is parsed as an ExpressionName:
ExpressionName:
  Identifier
  AmbiguousName . Identifier

AmbiguousName:
  Identifier
  AmbiguousName . Identifier

which is one of the options for a PostfixExpression, alongside Primary:
PostfixExpression:
  Primary
  ExpressionName
  PostIncrementExpression
  PostDecrementExpression 

When the JLS says that names and primary expressions "become interchangeable" at the level of precedence of postfix expressions, it means that both names and primary expressions can be parsed as postfix expressions. It does not mean that names become primary expressions.

Please look at the example in 15.11.1-1. According to the meaning of the specification, s seems to be regarded as an expression and a primary expression.Pay attention and look: "because the type of the expression s is S","Note that only the type of the Primary expression, not the class of the actual object referred to at run time, is used in determining which field to use."Perhaps there is something wrong with my understanding?

@user24723440: That example uses s.x, but that still doesn't mean that s is a Primary. It means they weren't careful about maintaining the technical distinction between a FieldAccess and an ExpressionName in this example. Either they thought that it'd distract from the point of the example, or the person writing that particular example wasn't aware of the distinction when they wrote it.

@user24723440 Examples are not normative. Take them with a grain of salt.

@user24723440 Also, there is no mention of "Primary" in example 15.11.1-1. The normative text before the example says that, but the text and the example are unrelated things that just so happens to be placed together.

@Sweeper  At present, it is indeed the case. They put the content related to ExpressionName into FieldAccess for analysis, which caused me to misunderstand.
